# Kotlin type mismatch on generic recursive function inside class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following class, which is meant to compute the set of all ordered sets:

```
class PowerSet<T>(val inputSet: List<T>, val minLength: Int = 4) {

    private var combinations = mutableListOf<MutableList<T>>()

    init {
        powerset(listOf(), inputSet)
    }

    private fun <T> powerset(curr: List<T>, left: List<T>) {

        if (curr.size > this.minLength) {
            combinations.add(curr)
        }

        if (left.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        for ((index, value) in left.withIndex()) {

            val subList = left.subList(0, index) + left.subList(index + 1, left.size)
            val newList = curr + listOf(value)
            powerset(newList, subList)
        }
    }
}
```

The following error occurs:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
MutableList<T#1 (type parameter of com.example.PowerSet)>
Found:
List<T#2 (type parameter of com.example.PowerSet.powerset)>
```

No idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your method `powerset` has its own type parameter `T`.

You should remove the `<T>` there because you want the `T` to be the same as the class's `T`:

```kotlin
private fun powerset(curr: List<T>, left: List<T>) {
  // ...
}
```

Then I think you may also have an issue with `List` vs `MutableList`.
`curr` is a `List<T>`, so you cannot add it to `combinations`, which expects elements of type `MutableList<T>`.

You can use `toMutableList()` to convert your `List` into `MutableList`:

```kotlin
combinations.add(curr.toMutableList())
```